# How to change border as div height increases

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div which contains a textarea. This div has a border:1px solid black. Now when the user types in textarea, the textarea grows.

I have this code -

```
$('#sendtext').on('input', function(){
        $this = $(this);
        var totalHeight = $this.prop('scrollHeight') - parseInt($this.css('padding-top')) - parseInt($this.css('padding-bottom'));
        $this.height(totalHeight);
        $div = $('#sendmsg');
        $div.height($div.prop('scrollHeight') - parseInt($div.css('padding-top')) - parseInt($div.css('padding-bottom')))
    });
```

Now the outer div (outer to textarea) grows with it. But this change in height is not reflected in the border. The border stays there. How can I achieve that, if it is possible.

**PS - My outer dive grows in height, when I see that in my Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+I), but the border does not reflect that change.**

[image: I want this black border to grow with the textarea]

HTML -

```
<div id="sendmsg">
                                    <textarea id="sendtext" value="">
                                    </textarea>
                                    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
                                </div>
```

CSS -

```
#sendmsg{width:100%; height:auto;}
#sendtext{width:95%; margin:10px; padding:5px; transition: width 0.25s; resize:none; overflow:hidden;}
.clearBoth{clear:both;}
```

Comment: Can you please show HTML or include an example (e.g. from JSFiddle)? This would make it a lot easier to answer.

Comment: please put the HTML and CSS code here

Answer (score 1):

Hi i created a JSFiddle for you here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/81kvgjaz/3/)
hope this helps

HTML

```
<div>
    <textarea id='grow'></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
   width: 400px;
   border:solid 1px #333;
   padding:10px;
}
textarea{
   overflow: hidden;
   min-height: 50px;
   max-height: 100px;
}
```

Javascript/jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#grow').keyup(function(e) {
      $(this).css('height','5px');
      var a = document.getElementById('grow').scrollHeight+'px';
      $(this).css('height',a);
   });
});
```

Comment: I think, I am doing a similar thing. But mine doesnt work. Can you please find what am I doing wrong? I have also added my HTML and CSS. I appreciate your help.

Also, PS - My outer dive grows in height, when I see that in my Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+I), but the border does not reflect that change.

Comment: Okay i will try it in JSFiddle wait

Comment: holy mother of god ! why then its not working on the php app that I am building? Can you think of any reason which I can explore?

And I am using chrome.

Comment: an app that I am building.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this.It may help you

HTML CODE:

```
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
div{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;

}
textarea{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box 
}
```

Check the  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/letmedoit/81kvgjaz/)

Comment: I dont want a scroll bar in my textarea.

Comment: use `overflow:hidden` property @NalinAgrawal

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#sendtext').on('input', function() {
  $this = $(this);
  var totalHeight = $this.prop('scrollHeight') - parseInt($this.css('padding-top')) - parseInt($this.css('padding-bottom'));
  $this.height(totalHeight);
  $div = $('#sendmsg');
  $div.height($div.prop('scrollHeight') - parseInt($div.css('padding-top')) - parseInt($div.css('padding-bottom')))
});
```

```css
#sendmsg {

  width: 100%;

  height: auto;

  border: 1px solid #000;

}

#sendtext {

  width: 95%;

  margin: 10px;

  padding: 5px;

  transition: width 0.25s;

  resize: none;

  overflow: hidden;

}

.clearBoth {

  clear: both;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sendmsg">
  <textarea id="sendtext" value="">
  </textarea>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

I'have shared your code here, but I don't see any issue, its working fine here

Comment: Yeah ! I see. But its not working working when I am using it. It works fine here. Can you think of some possible reasons which I can explore?

Comment: try giving `*{box-sizing:border-box}` in your CSS file at the top.